# Amazon S3 folder permissions

Tags: amazon-s3

I am planning to map an Amazon S3 bucket as a basic shared folder/file server using TNT drive.
I've managed to map a drive in Windows perfectly fine I just need to lock down the shared folder permissions. I have some unix experience but I'm completely baffled by the Amazon permissions commands, if the folder path is;

```
'MyBucket/Shares/LON1'
```

& the user group is

```
'Design'
```

how can I grant the Design group the usual read/write/delete/list contents/create folder permissions for the folder 'LON1' but no higher?
Thanks very much,

Comment: S3 is, at a fundamental level, not a file system. Do not depend on its permissions to behave quite how you expect.

Comment: ok thanks I'll bear it in mind, having second thoughts already about the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use IAM to assign permissions to buckets. Each user will have it's own `Access Key ID` and `Secret Access Key`.  You can restrict access to the bucket and folders based on the policies you attach to the user or the group that the user belong to.

For example the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1388785271000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/objectpath"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

will allow the user or group to do all possible actions on bucketname/objectpath.

Here's a walkthrough from Amazon:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/walkthrough1.html

Comment: thankyou slayed, although in the above example what is the user group or does "Sid": "Stmt1388785271000" refer to access key & secret access key? Its only a small group so I'd be happy to enter permissions individually.

Comment: `Stmt1388785271000` is just a statement Id. It can be any string for example `AllowAccessToBucketNameObjectPath`. Check the walkthrough link that I added to the original response.

Comment: ok thanks for all your help, I will have a play with it & hopefully work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following policy to restrict the user to upload or list objects only to specific folders. I have created a policy that allows me to list only the objects of folder1 and folder2, and also allows to put the object to folder1 and deny uploads to other folders of the buckets. The policy does as below: 1.List all the folders of bucket 2.List objects and folders of allowed folders 3.Uploads files only to allowed folders

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
    "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
    "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::"]
}, {
    "Sid": "AllowListingOfFolder1And2",
    "Action": ["s3:"],
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"],
    "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
            "s3:prefix": ["folder1/", "folder2/"]
        },
        "StringLike": {
            "s3:prefix": ""
        }
    }
}, {
    "Sid": "Allowputobjecttofolder1only",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "NotResource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/folder1/"
}]
```

}